# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $ in QAF

Tags: java, cucumber, qaf

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $

**Feature file:**
In the feature file I am passing one parameter

```
Feature: WebTableScneario 
Scenario: Demo WebTableScneario

Given I login to application
And I select the country
|Country|
|UAE|
Then I logout the application
```

**StepDef:**

```
@QAFTestStep(description ="I login to application") 
      public void user_is_on_loginpage() {
      
         
          System.out.println("Login Page Step def");
      }
    
    @QAFTestStep(description ="I select the country{0}") 
      public void user_selectCountry(List<Map<String,String>> countrydetails) {
      System.out.println("select the country");
      }
      
    @QAFTestStep(description ="I logout the application") 
      public void user_logout() {
      System.out.println("logout");
      }

}
```

Can anyone please into this and help me
But When I am running facing below exception
[image: Console log]

Answer (score 0):

This looks potential bug for corner case. A quick fix can be as below:

```
And I select the country
|Country||
|UAE||
```

Alternately, the method signature can be changed to accept Map instead of List of Map or List of String/Object if you are expecting only one property in list.

Update: Refer [issue 401](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/issues/401)